# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': xpath

Tags: python, selenium

[image: Textbox - input]

Element:

XPATH:
`//*[@id="autocomplete_code"]`

I am getting syntax error for below statement, what is not correct in this xpath? I tried just with `id` and both `id` & `class`.

```
account  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*input[@id='autocomplete_code' and @class = 'account_code_ac inputSearch ui-autocomplete-input']")
```

Answer (score 0):

changing code as below fixed the syntax error, but still not able to select the search result value with arrow down key

```
account  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='autocomplete_code']")
account.send_keys("1100-1200-200167-620038")
account.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
account.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Make sure you have the right input tag that could be grabbing any element right now.

Answer (score 0):

changing code as below works fine:

```
account =driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@aria-label='Search an Account']").click()
account  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='autocomplete_code']")
account.send_keys("1100-1200-200167-620038")
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@aria-label, "1100-1200-200167-620038")]')))
account.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
account.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).